# Possible efficient ways of creating a timetable in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've been trying to create a timetable and I have tried different layouts, the best i could get is to use a grid layout.
a preview of how it looks:
[image]

The header is a fixed view, I added that manually in the xml file.
but each of the "Off white" cells and cells that contains time are textviews added dynamically using a loop.
However I think it's not the most efficient way of creating this, also I wouldn't be able to locate those cells unless I add an id to each of them dynamically and store those Ids.
This example shows an empty time table. but those cells should be able to expand and merge with others when an event is added.
Is Grid Layout the only way to build this and is there more a more efficient way to locate each cell position?

this is similar to what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: `android studio` is for questions about the IDE. `android` is for asking questions about the framework, using the wrong tags will result in people not seeing your questions